# How to make a widget occupy the same width as that of its master frame when using columnspan?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

Given the following grid layout configuration:

[image]

It was generated through code:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(master, width=100, height=100, bg="red")
frame1.grid(sticky="nsew", columnspan=4)

frame2 = Frame(master, width=100, height=100, bg="blue")
frame2.grid()

frame3 = Frame(master, width=100, height=100, bg="green")
frame3.grid(row=1, column=1)

frame4 = Frame(master, width=100, height=100, bg="yellow")
frame4.grid(row=1, column=2)

frame4 = Frame(master, width=100, height=100, bg="purple")
frame4.grid(row=1, column=3)

master.mainloop()
```

I tried to insert a `Entry` in `frame1` so it extends to the whole `frame1` width with the following code:

```
e1 = Entry(frame1)
e1.grid(sticky="we", columnspan=4)
```

However, I have got the following result:

[image]

How can I make the `Entry` widget occupy the same width as the `frame1`?

Comment: BTW: setting the height and width of a Frame only lasts as long as the Frame is empty. As soon as you put something in a Frame the size is set by the size of the widgets inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry is inside `frame1`, so the grid it is in is completely unrelated to the grid in the root window.

Since you didn't tell tkinter what to do with extra space inside `frame1`, it left it unused. If you want the entry widget which is in column 0 to fill the frame, you need to give its column a weight.

```
frame1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

If this is the only widget going in `frame1`, you might want to consider using `pack` since you can do it all in one line of code:

```
e1.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
```

Comment: Any reason you use the grid_ prefix instead of just `frame1.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`?

Comment: @Novel: no reason. Just an old habit.